# How to resolve the Android Studio files code changing error?

Tags: android

After create the project in Android Studio and run that project it's works fine after some days reopen the same project for modifications it shows the all Java and xml files code as ascii characters how to rectify that please any one help me

1. clean project
2. bulid project
3. files -> invalidate caches/restart

Comment: what about invalidate caches/restart ?

Comment: Actually I  open files module in android studio in that module I click on the invalidate cache / restart option to resolve the above problem